# Looking for a single timing method to test various algorithms excluding their inputs

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Assume that I have several algorithms to test as follows.

```
void AlgoA(int x)
{
    // critical operations go here 
}

void AlgoB(int x, int y)
{
    // critical operations go here
}
```

## First Approach

I define `Timer` that accepts parameterless pointer to function.

```
void Timer(void (*f)(), unsigned short N = 1)
{
    vector<unsigned long long> results;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        f();
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

        unsigned long long interval = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();
        results.push_back(interval);
        cout << "Elapsed time: " << interval << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for (unsigned long long x : results)
        sum += x;
    cout << "Average: " << sum / results.size() << endl;
}
```

Wrappers are needed to prepare  the inputs.

```
void DoA()
{
    int x;
    // preparing  x goes here

    AlgoA(x);
}
void DoB()
{
    int x, y;
    // preparing  x and y goes here

    AlgoB(x, y);
}
void main()
{
    Timer(DoA);
    Timer(DoB);
}
```

Cons: `Timer` also counts the time elapsed for preparing inputs.

Pros: General `Timer` for many algo tests.

## Second Approach

I have to write 2 timers, each for an algorithm to test.

```
void TimerA(void (*f)(int), int x, unsigned short N = 1)
{
    vector<unsigned long long> results;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        f(x);
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

        unsigned long long interval = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();
        results.push_back(interval);
        cout << "Elapsed time: " << interval << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for (unsigned long long x : results)
        sum += x;
    cout << "Average: " << sum / results.size() << endl;
}
void TimerB(void (*f)(int, int), int x, int y, unsigned short N = 1)
{
    vector<unsigned long long> results;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        f(x, y);
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

        unsigned long long interval = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();
        results.push_back(interval);
        cout << "Elapsed time: " << interval << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for (unsigned long long x : results)
        sum += x;
    cout << "Average: " << sum / results.size() << endl;
}



void main()
{
    int x;
    // preparing x goes here.
    TimerA(AlgoA, x);

    int y;
    // preparing y goes here.
    TimerB(AlgoB, x, y);
}
```

Pros: Timers count only the critical operations.

Cons: Multiple timers, each for an algo to test.

## Question

Is there any way to just create a single `Timer` but it must not count the time needed to prepare the inputs?

## Edit:

The inputs are actually not just `int` but `struct`, etc that may be retrieved from time-dependent IO.

Comment: the questions is not quite clear. Why do you time `DoA` instead of simply measuring `AlgoA(x);` if thats what you want to measure?

Comment: just as you pass `DoA` and `DoB` in the first approach you can pass `AlgoA` or `AlgoB` to the timer

Comment: I suggest using [quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/) if you want something quick and online.  If you want to do it on your machine(s) then you can get [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark).

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thank you for the useful links. :-)

Comment: You could use a variadic template to capture the argument types and then use std::forward to pass them to your test subject.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit yes, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit, I dont see the problem. Maybe the problem is that you overspecified what you want to do. If you want to pass a callable to a method and call it that would be:

```
template <typename F>
void call_it(F f) {
    // start timer
    f();
    // stop timer
}
```

Now you can pass almost anything to it, for example:

```
int x = some_expensive_precalculation();
call_it( [&]() { method_to_time(x); });
```

Note that you might experience a tiny overhead due to not calling the function directly. However, I expect this to be negligible compared to anything that is worth measuring and with compiler optimizations there might be no overhead at all.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit sorry typo, the `&` was in the wrong place. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

If you want to always prepare your inputs outside of the timer, you can use `std::function` with `std::bind`

```
void timer(std::function<void()> algorithm, unsigned short N = 1) {
    // your timer code here
}

void algoA(int x)
{
    // critical operations go here 
}

void algoB(int x, int y)
{
    // critical operations go here
}

int main() {
    int x, y;  // prepare input
    timer(std::bind(algoA, x));
    timer(std::bind(algoB, x, y));
}
```

Comment: How to call `algorithm` in the `timer`? just `algorithm();` is enough?

Comment: you can use lambda syntax '[&]{algoB(x,y);}' instead of 'bind'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use variadic templates and forward the arguments to your test subject.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename ... Args>
void benchmark(void (*f)(Args...), unsigned short N, Args&&... args)
{
    vector<unsigned long long> results;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    unsigned long long interval = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();
    results.push_back(interval);
    cout << "Elapsed time: " << interval << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for (unsigned long long x : results)
    sum += x;
    cout << "Average: " << sum / results.size() << endl;
}

void fun(int a, float b, char c) {

}

int main() {

    benchmark(fun, 500, 42, 3.1415f, 'A');

    return 0;
}
```

I *think* there is no way to have the default argument for `N` with this approach. But maybe this is not so important for you.

Comment: All answers are useful. But now I got confused which one is the fastest. Benchmarking the benchmarkers.

Comment: This one uses perfect forwarding, so no copying of arguments is involved. However, I don't think that it makes any difference. Because the setup of the benchmark is performed once and `N` may become very large. Unless you intended to generate fresh input for every iteration (which needs some generator function or coroutine-like generator), you should be fine with this one.